# Excel formula to return a value from a range where conditional statements are true

Tags: excel, conditional-statements

I've searched for an answer for this for awhile now but haven't had any luck. It's a bit difficult to put into words, so please let me know if anything's unclear.

What I want is a way to perform conditional statements on two columns. When both conditions are true, I want to return the value from a third column that is in the same row as where these conditions were met.  So if the conditions are true in D5 and C5, I want to return the value from Q5 into the cell with the formula.  The conditional statements are easy enough but I haven't figured out the last step yet.

If I use the following formula, I get 1 in the cell with the formula, which is right.

```
=IF(AND('Stata Output'!D2:D6='Backcheck schedule and results'!C2, 'Stata Output'!C2:C6=1),1,0)
```

However, replacing 1 in the formula with the range of cells that I want to pull the value from gives me a zero every time, which I know is wrong.  For this latter formula I'm using:

```
=IF(AND('Stata Output'!D2:D6='Backcheck schedule and results'!C2, 'Stata Output'!C2:C6=1),'Stata Output'!Q2:Q5,0)
```

Any ideas on where I'm messing up?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Give this a shot - I'm sure there is a simpler way but it seems to get the job done (make sure to enter as an array formula with `Control+Shift+Enter`):

```
=INDEX('Stata Output'!$D$2:$Q$6,MATCH(1,(--('Stata Output'!$C$2:$C$6=1)*--('Stata Output'!$D$2:$D$6="Backcheck schedule and results")),0),14)
```

What this does is take your entire table as the range (first argument to `INDEX`, then uses `MATCH` to find the row where both of your conditions are met (in this case, column `C` must be `1` and the corresponding value in column `D` must be `Backcheck schedule and results`). You then search the resulting array for 1 (which indicates the match) and return column `14` (which represents column `Q` in our table). You can continue to add filters inside the `MATCH()` function as needed.

Note that this will match only the first 'hit'.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following formula:

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/('Stata Output'!D2:D6='Backcheck schedule and results'!C2)/('Stata Output'!C2:C6=1),'Stata Output'!Q2:Q5)
```

If there is more than one row where both conditions are satisfied, this formula will return the col `Q` value from the **last** of those.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `AND` isn't working correctly in array formulas, so I would use this:

```
=IF(('Stata Output'!D2:D6='Backcheck schedule and results'!C2)*('Stata Output'!C2:C6=1)=1,'Stata Output'!Q2:Q5,0)
```

This will give you a new results column, that will be filled from the `Q2:Q6` column for every matching row.

To use it, you should select all of the results column, input the formula and then use `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER`.

Just make sure to use use ranges of the same size.

Comment: Yes, you are correct about AND, the result of AND is a single result rather than an array.....but the problem with your revised version is that it produces an "array", e.g. if row 3 matches but the others don't then you'd get {0;text;0;0;0} where text is the value in Q3.....so you need some other function to extract that value from the array (see my answer and RocketDonkey's) - if entered in a single cell you'd typically see just the first value from that array (the 0) but that can change depending on where you enter the formula!

Comment: @barryhoudini, yes, it gives an array of results, and this formula should be applied to a range of cells. I guess I understood the question differently, that he wants to get the results for all of the matching rows, and not only one of them.